# Dynamic getters and settings for classes in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a problem to retrieve data with dynamic getter on my class.

Here is the error I get:

> Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'UserProps'.
>     No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type 'UserProps'.ts(7053)

Here is the code

```
interface UserProps {
  name?: string;
  age?: number;
}

export class User {
  constructor(private data: UserProps) {}

  get(propName: string): number | string {
    return this.data[propName];
  }

  set(update: UserProps): void {
    Object.assign(this.data, update);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The cleanest solution I could find is the following:

```
interface UserProps {
    name?: string;
    age?: number;
}

export class User {
    constructor(private data: UserProps) {}

    // Add generic magic here
    get<K extends keyof UserProps>(propName: K): UserProps[K] {
        return this.data[propName];
    }

    set(update: UserProps): void {
        Object.assign(this.data, update);
    }
}
```

Alternatively, you can add an arbitrary key indexing as well as update the type for your get statement.

```
interface UserProps {
    name?: string;
    age?: number;
    // this next line is important
    [key: string]: string | number | undefined;
}

export class User {
    constructor(private data: UserProps) {}

    // number|string changed to number|string|undefined
    get(propName: string): number | string | undefined {
        return this.data[propName];
    }

    set(update: UserProps): void {
        Object.assign(this.data, update);
    }
}
```

Comment: this works but it make me sad to have to write this to make it work

Comment: An alternative that doesn't involve the `[key: string]` line is changing your get function signature to `get(propName: "name" | "age"): number | string | undefined`.

Comment: I understand now where is the problem. Thanks for the solution. I'm kinda sad that we have to rewrite all the types of attributes in all cases. I can't believe there is no better solution than this.

Comment: @MichaelT. It appears that I have missed a much cleaner solution, and I have edited my answer to include it. Hopefully that can help you.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This is a great solution.

Comment: @MichaelT. Glad I could help you! It's a bit early in the day so I forgot about typescript's generic magic.